# DateTime render different formats

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

All over my website my dates renders in the format i want, **yyyy-mm-dd**.
But for some views(two out of 20) it renders **dd/mm/yyyy**.

Checked:

- Culture settings,  sv-SE
- File encodings, utf-8
- Viewmodels don't differ anything,
- html lang sv, charset utf-8
- Dates are the same in db tables.

What am I missing here?

I can't get my head around this issue.

**UPDATE**

The dates are loaded in the views like this:

```
    DateTime datum = item.AnswerDate; 
@Html.FriendlyCreatedDate(datum);

    public static String FriendlyCreatedDate(this HtmlHelper helper, DateTime startDate)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(startDate.Created());
        return sb.ToString();
    }
     public static string Created(this DateTime d)
    {
        string today = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        string yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
        string tomorroww = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString();

        if (d.ToShortDateString() == yesterday)
        {
            return "Igår, kl "+d.ToShortTimeString();
        }
        if (d.ToShortDateString() == tomorroww)
        {
            return "Imorgon, kl " + d.ToShortTimeString();
        }
        if (d.ToShortDateString() == today)
        {
            return "Idag, kl " + d.ToShortTimeString();
        }
        return d.ToShortDateString() + ", " + d.ToShortTimeString();

    }
```

Comment: Show the code of the two views where you output the date

Comment: They are real *DateTime* objects when loaded?

Comment: I have updated my questions with details about the output. 
But be aware that this is done for _all_ dates on my site. And only two of them renders in a different format.

If i output the dates without the helper I still get the wrong format.

Comment: This might sound crazy but try renaming the properties for the dates that don't work. I had a very similar issue myself though I wanted dd-mmm-yyyy format. In the end it appear to be an issue with the property, renaming them fixed the issue. If anyone knows why I would love to know.

Comment: I actually tried that earlier but it did not solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have particular cases without the global culture info. You can specified the format in the ToString() function or directly in the string formater.

see this example :

```
DateTime v_Date = new DateTime(2013, 12, 22);

Console.WriteLine("{0}", v_Date);

Console.WriteLine("{0}", v_Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyy"));

Console.WriteLine("{0:dd/MM/yyy}", v_Date);
```

Comment: This caused all other dates to strange numbers... :/
like 2013-22-50